# How to Deal with structural breakpoints?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, structural-change

well, recently, when estimating a regression model in R, I found multiple structural breaks.  Reading on the subject, I noticed that such breaks can cause problems.  Given this, what would be the possible solutions to this problem?

When using the strucchange package in R, several breaks were found in my data, investment data, industrial capacity utilization and loans. As an output for the test, I got the following result:

```
Optimal 5-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = FBCFdef ~ empredef + uticap, breaks = 5, 
    data = df)

Breakpoints at observation number:
37 84 160 197 

Corresponding to breakdates:
0.1468254 0.3333333 0.6349206 0.781746
```

Comment: For general information, see the tag info about [`structural-change`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/structural-change/info). Please edit your question to provide much more detail about your particular situation if you want more direct help.

Comment: thank you for the tips